# Replacing values closest to Nan with a value, within a matrix, in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, replace, find

I am new to Matlab and I have a matrix:

```
M =[NaN NaN NaN 2010 5454;
    NaN NaN 2009 3000 5000
    NaN 2011 3256 5454 6000
    2009 4000 5666 6545 5555
    5000 5666 6000 7000 8000];
```

I want to replace values closest to Nan with a value of 2010. I know how to do it manually and one by one. Is there any to create a loop to find these values and replace them? The result should look like this:

```
M =[NaN NaN NaN 2010 5454;
    NaN NaN 2010 3000 5000
    NaN 2010 3256 5454 6000
    2010 4000 5666 6545 5555
    5000 5666 6000 7000 8000];
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you define "closeness"? 4-neighbourhood (up, down, left, right) or 8-neighbourhood (includes diagonals)?

Comment: I've posted a simple solution assuming you are looking for 4-neighbors, please check if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible without defining any explicit loops. Below are the steps and sample code.

- Use the `find` function to determine which elements are `NaN`.
- Then, offset those indices by 1 both in the positive and negative direction to find positions of neighboring elements.
- Finally replace all such locations with required value, after deleting those positions that are outside the array.

#### Sample code

```
% Row and column indices of NaN in array `a`
[x, y] = find(isnan(a));

% All 4-neighbor elements around each NaN
r = [x-1 x+1 x x];
c = [y y y-1 y+1];

% Delete those values that are outside the array bounds
% (For NaNs in the edges)
outInd = r < 1 | r > size(a, 1) | c < 1 | c > size(a, 2);
r(outInd) = [];
c(outInd) = [];

% Replace all these neighbors with required value
a(sub2ind(size(a), r, c)) = 2010;
```

Comment: Glad! Sure, I believe you did not complete typing your comment, what's after "For instance:"?

Comment: Sorry:Your solution has worked very well. I just want to know how to tweak one thing. In stead of making the limit a fixed value of "2010", which is a vertical straight line, I want to make it a curve. For instance, a parabola:                                                                                                     `HardLimx=2100:100:4300; 
HardLimy=0.001*HardLimx.^2+3000;`                                                          I have tried substituting the "2010" value with HardLimy, also my means of a for loop, but to no success. Could you please offer some help?

Comment: Do the x and y correspond to the row and column index? I mean, how would you generate `HardLimx` and `HardLimy` without knowing how much replacements are to be made, and what the indices are?

Comment: Now that you mention it, it should. My original M matrix 23x10, which fits with this hardLimx I just gave I think. Put for the purpose of the question I gave on this page which has a simplified M matrix 5x5, let me change the hardLimx to `HardLimx    = 3900:100:4300;` ? Is this better?

Comment: I realize I might be totally wrong. You are free to propose a different solution. I have no success this side. Thanks again.

Comment: I have created a new question in which I try to exsplain fully: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932390/replacing-values-closest-to-nan-with-a-value-within-a-matrix-in-matlab-rev2

Answer (score 3):

*Thanks to [@crazyGamer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3998255/crazygamer) for improving the answer with explanations and clearer variable names.*

---

You can use 2D-convolution to detect entries that are close to a `NaN`; select non-`NaN`'s among those entries, and write the desired value there.

Closeness is defined by means of a neighbourhood binary mask. This usually has `4` neighbours (up, down, left, right) or `8` (including diagonals).

The code is generalized to use either mask as per choice.

### Solution

```
% Data:
M = [ NaN NaN NaN 2010 5454;
      NaN NaN 2009 3000 5000;
      NaN 2011 3256 5454 6000;
      2009 4000 5666 6545 5555;
      5000 5666 6000 7000 8000 ];

neighbourhood = [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0];
% or [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1] for 8-neighbours

new_value = 2010;

% Computations:
nanInds = isnan(M);
nanIndsWithNeighs = conv2(nanInds, neighbourhood, 'same')~=0;
neighInds = ~nanInds & nanIndsWithNeighs; % logical AND

M(neighInds) = new_value;
```

Comment: For anyone comfortable with convolution or familiar with image processing, this is a beautiful solution! :)

Comment: And for all the rest... get comfortable with convolution! :-D

Comment: If you don't mind, I would like to edit the post to add more comments to explain what is happening, to those who may not be familiar.

Comment: @crazyGamer Sure, go ahead!

Comment: @crazyGamer Thanks! I had to change `.*` to `&` so the result was of `logical` type